# How to create a static TabControl in XAML WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, tabcontrol

I need to create a TabControl in MainWindow, and then I need to make a Property in MainWindow that returns that TabControl. I don't know how to access TabControl from another window because it says "An object reference is required bla bla..." when I try like this:

```
MainWindow.tabcontrol.Items.Add("tabitem");
```

and the Property I made in MainWindow is:

```
public TabControl tabcontrol
{ get { return tabc; } set{ tabc = value;} }
```

Values are:

```
"tabcontrol" is name of Property
"tabc" is name of TabControl that I need in another window
```

Please, how do I do this? How to add items to a TabControl that is in MainWindow from another window?

this code returns error saying : "An object reference is required..."

Comment: post your xaml + exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the TabControl in XAML and give it name. Your can use that name in code behind:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" ... />
```

In code behind just use MyTabControl.