# How can I make a control in a Template/Style so that it can be accessed?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I've re-templated the Silverlight ChildWindow class to allow for various customizations. So far so good. I added a `StackPanel` to the title bar so that I can add some menu buttons to it, but I don't know how to make the `StackPanel` front facing. There's probably several ways to do what I'm trying to do, but really all I want is to be able to access this stackpanel from code so that I can add some things to it.

The ChildWindow Header bar is referred to as the Chrome. This is what I have.

```
<Border x:Name="Chrome" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
   <Border.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0.528" StartPoint="0.5,0">
         <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E8EB" Offset="1" />
         <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="0" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Border.Background>
   <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackPanel Name="TitleBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,6,0"  >
         <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" IsTabStop="False" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,6,0" />
         <StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  x:Name="stackPanel_menu_buttons" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </StackPanel>
      <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="14" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

Is there some eacy way for me to make `stackPanel_menu_buttons` a public object?

Comment: Is that what you Need?: [x:Name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073869/how-to-create-a-static-tabcontrol-in-xaml-wpf

Comment: @gomi42 It is not. This isn't on the window itself, it's in a template, and I don't know how to make something in a template accessible.

Comment: `to be able to access this stackpanel from code so that I can add some things to it` - You don't do that in WPF. Create a proper ViewModel and use an `ItemControl` to show your items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with HighCore. In case you still want to do it. Just set the x:Name and access this way:

```
yourControl = GetTemplateChild("YourControlsXName") as FrameworkElement;
```