# Find Element in ContentControl Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ContentControl which ContentTemplate is bound to a DataTemplate, containing a Grid(Or some sort of Panel).

How can I access the Grid inside the ContentContorl?

ContentControl

```
<ContentControl
    x:Key="InputControl"
    Content="{Binding}"
    ContentTemplate="{Binding InputTemplate.Template}" />
```

DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SpeechOutputTemplate">
    <Grid Height="100" Margin="132,0" x:Name="RootElement">
        <!-- content -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Using `InputControl.FindName("RootElement")` doesn't seem to work for me.

Btw. is there an event, which is fired, after the ContentTemplate changed?

Comment: Have a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075440/how-can-i-make-a-control-in-a-template-style-so-that-it-can-be-accessed/21075638#21075638)

Comment: whatever you're trying to do, use DataBinding

Comment: Sure.. I would do that, if you could say me how.. inside the DataTemplate is a Storyboard, which have to be started and stoped on certain events, raised in code behin(awaitable..)

Answer (score 2):

[FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`GetTemplateChild` returns the named `element` in the visual tree or `null` if no element of the requested name exists.

```
FrameworkElement mElement = GetTemplateChild("InputControl") as FrameworkElement;
```

Comment: At StackOverflow, we prefer answers to include words... please add a basic explanation to your answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.. maybe it's because the DataTemplate is applied to ContentTemplate? Teleriks `FindChildByType` works, but is not excatly for what Im looking for, because this Method search for a certain type and instead of an name